# which is the best ways to learn ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Actually I'm new user in Ubuntu. I try to learn it's terminal uses.But i don't know how to should to learn it steps by steps.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Comment: In addition to the link mentioned in the above comment, you can ask **specific** questions at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, you should just install and drive it. There is no tutorial that can replace old school user research. If you are curious enough, you will learn everything you want quickly.

Anyway, you can check out those links to get a head start:

[Top 17 commands for Ubuntu Beginners](http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/07/20/top-17-terminal-commands-every-ubuntu-user-should-know-about/)

[The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php)